# LASSO Cox Model after multiple imputation

Tags: survival, model-selection, missing-data, lasso, independence

I want to develop a predictive survival model on a data set with about 8000 subjects and 38 covariates. About 4% of subjects had the event of interest. 
There are 21 variables with missing values, with up to 35% missing per variable.

[Musoro et al. (2014)](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-14-116) have recommended to use LASSO in combination with bootstrap and multiple imputation for this scenario. Their approach is a generalization of 
[Heymans et al (2007)](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2288-7-33) which was summarized in Stef van Buurens [excellent book.](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-stepwise.html)

In short, they recommend to create $m$ bootstrap datasets from the incomplete dataset, and then impute each of the $m$ incomplete bootstrap datasets with $n$ multiple imputations, creating $m\cdot n$ complete datasets. Then LASSO is used on each of the data sets.

I am concerned about the pooling of the LASSO coefficients of the separate $m\cdot n$ models. I have two questions

1. There are different subjects in each of the datasets. Are Rubins rules applicable in this scenario? If yes, how can I estimate the variance between the datasets?
2. Are the pooled coefficients still valid LASSO coefficients? Do they fulfil the constraint that the absolute norm is smaller than the threshold? Can they be interpreted like maximum likelihood coefficients?

Lastly, if you think LASSO is not adequate here, please tell me why! I am grateful for any piece of advice!